# Question about the formulation of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, svm

The formulation of the SVM optimization problem is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& max_{w,b} \frac{1}{||w||} \\
& \text{ subject to } \\
& y_i(w^{T}x_i+b) \geq 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

What I do not understand is why do we use $w^Tx_i+b=1$ in the setup. My question is specifically about why 1? I understand that $w^Tx_i+b$ is the equation of a hyperplane and multiplying it by binary class labels $y_i \in \{-1,1\}$ we get the inequality but why do we initially not use $w^Tx_i+b = 2$ or 0 or any number. I am assuming we can adjust for this number since we have b as a hyperparameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The goal of a hard-margin SVM (you didn't mention slack variables, $\xi$, for soft-margin SVMs) is to minimize the Euclidean norm $||\mathbf{w}||$ to impose the inequality $y_i D(\mathbf{x}_i)/||\mathbf{w}||>1$ (Boser et al, 1992).  This is accomplished by using both the margin value $M$ and the weight vector $\mathbf{w}$ and enforcing the constraint $M ||\mathbf{w}||=1$, which when solving for the optimal margin gives $M=1/||\mathbf{w}||$.

For hard-margin SVMs, the unconstrained Lagrangian function is also
\begin{equation}
L({\bf w},b,\boldsymbol{\alpha})=\frac{1}{2}{\bf w}^T{\bf w}  - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i [y_i ({\bf w}^T{\bf x}_i + b) - 1 ]\\
\end{equation}

$ s.t.\quad \quad \alpha_i \geq 0, \quad    y_i ({\bf w}^T{\bf x}_i + b) - 1=0$

**Reference:**

B.E. Boser, I.M. Guyon, V.N. Vapnik.  A training algorithm for optimal margin classifiers. $\textit{Proc. 5th Annual Work. Comp. Learning Theory (COLT'95),}$ pp. 144-152.  New York (NY), ACM Press, 1992.

Comment: thanks for your answer @nxglogic, I am wondering why the hyperplane equation we use is $w^Tx_i + b= 1$ instead of $w^Tx_i + b = 0$